# Spring data query for finding nodes which don't have a specific relationship

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I've got a node:

```
    @NodeEntity
    public class Category {

        @GraphId
        private Long id;
        private String title;
        @Relationship(type = "PARENT")
        private Category parent;
    }
```

Is there a "findBy..." method, which will return all the categories which don't have a parent?

I've tried findByParentIsNull(), findByParentIdIsNull(), etc. These didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not supported for the moment.
You have to use a cypher query like :

```
@Query("MATCH (u:User) WHERE NOT (u)-[:PARENT]-(:Category) RETURN u")
```

If you use it frequently and think it can be useful, feel free to open a feature request for it.